# How can I update multiple data variables of chart js label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to dynamically update my line chat with two data entry points with variable name "data"

see below

```
var lion =  new Chart(ctx2, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: ["Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Mobile apps",
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "#cb0c9f",
            borderWidth: 3,
            backgroundColor: gradientStroke1,
            fill: true,
            data: [50, 40, 300, 220, 500, 250, 400, 230, 500],
            maxBarThickness: 6

          },
          {
            label: "Websites",
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "#3A416F",
            borderWidth: 3,
            backgroundColor: gradientStroke2,
            fill: true,
            data: [30, 90, 40, 140, 290, 290, 340, 230, 400],
            maxBarThickness: 6
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          }
        },
        interaction: {
          intersect: false,
          mode: 'index',
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            grid: {
              drawBorder: false,
              display: true,
              drawOnChartArea: true,
              drawTicks: false,
              borderDash: [5, 5]
            },
            ticks: {
              display: true,
              padding: 10,
              color: '#b2b9bf',
              font: {
                size: 11,
                family: "Open Sans",
                style: 'normal',
                lineHeight: 2
              },
            }
          },
          x: {
            grid: {
              drawBorder: false,
              display: false,
              drawOnChartArea: false,
              drawTicks: false,
              borderDash: [5, 5]
            },
            ticks: {
              display: true,
              color: '#b2b9bf',
              padding: 20,
              font: {
                size: 11,
                family: "Open Sans",
                style: 'normal',
                lineHeight: 2
              },
            }
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

i tried dynamically updating using the method below :

```
  setInterval(function(){ 
    //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    

    lion.data.datasets[0].data = [getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100),getRandomInt(100),getRandomInt(100),getRandomInt(100),getRandomInt(100),getRandomInt(100),getRandomInt(100)],
//finally update chart var:
lion.update();



}, 2000);
```

this updates the data variable every 2 seconds.

I was expecting it would update data variable for both labels but it does not. It only updates the data for the "websites"

How do i target and update both data variables on both labels ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update all datasets, not only the first one you have.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    

  lion.data.datasets[0].data = [getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100)];
  lion.data.datasets[1].data = [getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100)];
  //finally update chart var:
  lion.update();

}, 2000);
```

Or instead of hardcoding you can loop over them

```js
setInterval(function() {
  //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    

  lion.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => dataset.data = [getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100), getRandomInt(100)]);
  //finally update chart var:
  lion.update();

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much how i have missed the [0] in the first example of updating charts is beyond me. thanks for bringing that to my attention